# prepared statement with Eloquent ORM / laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and use this as a input query:

```
DB::table('user_input')->insert(array(
                array('fname' => Input::get('Name'),'lname' => 'no','email' => Input::get('E-Mail'),'date_from' => $from_date,'date_to' => $to_date,'phone' => Input::get('Phone'),'message' => Input::get('Message'),'ip_address' => Request::getClientIp(), 'newsletter' => Input::get('Sign-up'))

            ));
```

which I would never do like that in standard php, as the query doesn't seem to be prepared and I put user input directly into above query.

Is there a automatic preparation in Eloquent ORM which I haven't recognized or how would I write a prepared statement with Eloquent?

Comment: What you have there will automatically use a prepared statement behind the scenes.

Comment: Just a note - this query has nothing to do with Eloquent. It is `Query\Builder`s insert method which doesn't even touch Eloquent features. Eloquent on the other hand, relies on the `Query\Builder` behind its own `Eloquent\Builder` class.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk thanks for the note, can you point me in the direction to a more "eloquent" way?

Comment: @baao Well, do you have any model for `user_input` table? If so, then simply use `Model::create(['fname' => ... ])` method. However, mind that you need to have those fields `fillable` in order to save them. If you don't have, then definitely no way to use Eloquent for this job :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent does the PDO style prepared statements behind the scenes to protect against things like sql injection. Eloquent models also protect against mass assignment by default. An exception will be thrown unless you specifically note the columns of the database that should be guarded or the inverse (the ones that should be fillable).

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment

If you want to dig further in, you can look at the class

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php`
```

to see how laravel constructs the queries in Eloquent.

Comment: mass assignement has nothing to do with PDO.