# Allowing special characters and code injection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, security

Is it safe to allow these special characters when validating a string? The user is currently allowed to send alpha numeric and the following special characters from the browser:

```
',.!&()_-
```

My main concern is code injection. I'm still learning Laravel and I understand it handles a lot security wise. I'd like to make sure I'm taking solid precautions for good security.

I have the following code which uses the PHP Laravel framework to validate on the server side:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'str' => 'bail|required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \',.!&_-]+$/u'
]);

$search_str = $request->str;

$query = Story::where('story_text', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_str.'%');
```

Is this sufficiently secure or is there more I should be doing?

Comment: when in doubt, use a prepared statement.

Comment: Since you're using Laravel, apparently this is already done for you. See this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131856/prepared-statement-with-eloquent-orm-laravel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using [raw](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/f720839f391eb4440f1609f93d68d46c2b54339f/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php#L221) SQL - which you are not in your example - then Laravel [handles](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/f720839f391eb4440f1609f93d68d46c2b54339f/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php#L235) this for you. From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries):

> The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

This is true as of 5.4, and has been true since at least 4.1.