# What is more secured to SQL Injection? DB::statement or DB::insert,update,delete in Laravel 5.5/5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

I have been using laravel for a month now. And I have been basing my database operations from this documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database

I can insert,update and delete using DB::statement($query);

What I want to know is how strong these against SQL Injections.

```
$name = "John Doe";
DB::statement("INSERT INTO tbusers(id,name) VALUES(1,'$name')"); //first query
DB::insert('INSERT INTO tbusers(id, name) VALUES(?, ?)', [1, $name]); //second query
```

What is more secured? The first query or the second query?

Comment: the prepared statement is more secure; hands down.

Comment: Why not Eloquent?

Comment: Yea eloquent for non time critical operations to release yourself from potential injection attack. I only use query builder when it's time sensitive and require it to be fast.

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131856/prepared-statement-with-eloquent-orm-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems like using eloquent is easier and more secure than using raw sql query.